Java LDAP RMI wrong host method execution
In a distributed system implemented with Java, RMI and LDAP, I have the following Node class:
public class Node extends UnicastRemoteObject implements NodeInterface, Serializable {

    public Nodo(String name, String registry) throws Exception {
        super();
        ...
    }

    public void method(String registry, String name) throws Exception {
        DirContext ldapContext = Utiles.createLDAPContext(this.registry);
        System.out.println(ldapContext.lookup("cn=" + name + ",ou=Nodes"));
        Node remote = (Node) ldapContext.lookup("cn=" + name + ",ou=Nodes");
        remote.method2("Message");
    }

    public void method2(String message) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(message);
    }
}

And, each client has a Launcher  class to create its own Node:
public class Launcher {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String registry = args[0];
        String nodeName = args[1];

        DirContext ldapContext = Utils.createLDAPContext(registry);
        Node newNode = new Node(nodeName, registry);
        registerNode(nodeName, newNode, ldapContext);        
    }

    private static void registerNode(String nodeName, Node node, DirContext ldapContext) throws Exception {
        Attributes attributes = new BasicAttributes();
        attributes.put(new BasicAttribute("objectClass", "javaContainer"));
        attributes.put(new BasicAttribute("cn", nodeName));

        ldapContext.rebind("cn=" + nodeName + ",ou=Nodes", node, attributes);
        System.out.println("Node registered successfully with name: " + nodeName);
    }
}


The problem is that when I invoke Launcher and create several Nodes in the system, I want to execute method2() in a remote object, so I invoke method() in the object I have in my machine and give the registered name of the remote object as a parameter. The problem is that when I get the remote reference with lookup() and call method2(), the message gets printed on my machine, not in remote object console.
This is what the output of the remote object looks like:
Node[UnicastServerRef [liveRef: [endpoint:[192.168.56.1:60014](local),objID:[-53f66d6:18f160a3009:-7ffe, 6389968686518309714]]]]


You’re not doing this right. You need to use javaMarshalledObject. See RFC2713. And your remote object doesn’t need Serializable.

@user207421 Now it works, but when I try to run in several machines, the IP endpoint of one of them is 192.168.56.1, when the real discoverable is 192.168.1.128, resulting in a connection refused. What can be causing this?

Not sure I understand the question but maybe setting java.rmi.server.hostname in the JVM that exports that object is the answer. You need to set it before constructing the remote object.
